# Firebase functions take MINUTES to write in Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm building a mobile app and on some actions (like userCreate), I trigger some Firebase functions to perform an API call to a third service, and then write something in the Firestore database.

Everything works in theory, but in practice, the API calls are quite fast (even with cold start scenarios), but the database writes can take several MINUTES to complete (if they do at all, I suspect that sometimes it takes too long and times out).

Since the API call work just fine, and so does the DB write on some occasion, I suspect that this is simply due to **very** poor async management from me since I know about nothing in JS.

Here are two of many example functions which are concerned by this issue, just to showcase that it happens whereas I'm triggering functions onCreate or on HTTPS.

**onCreate function**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const axios = require('axios')

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access the Firestore.
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// Third party service credentials generation during onCreate request
exports.

buildCredentials = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {


// Request to Third party to generate an Client Access Token
axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api.ThirdParty.com/api/v1/oauth/token",
    data: "client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all:all",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log('new user created: ')
      console.log(user.id);
      console.log(response.data);
    
      // We write a new document in the users collection with the user ID and the Client Access Token
      const db = admin.firestore();
      const newUser = {
        uid: user.uid,
        clientAccessToken: response.data.access_token
      };

      db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(newUser)
      .catch(function (error) {
      //handle error
      console.log(error);
    });

    })
    .catch(function (response) {
      //handle error
      console.log(response);
    });
})
```

**HTTPS onCall function**

```
exports.paymentRequest = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const clientAccessToken = data.clientAccessToken;
    const recipientIban = data.recipientIban;
    const recipientName = data.recipientName;
    const paymentDescription = data.paymentDescription;
    const paymentReference = data.paymentReference;
    const productPrice = parseInt(data.productPrice);
    const uid = data.uid;

    const jsonData = {
        "destinations": [
                {
                    "accountNumber": recipientIban,
                    "type": "iban"          
                }
            ],
            "amount": productPrice,
            "currency": "EUR",
            "market": "FR",
            "recipientName": recipientName,
            "sourceMessage": paymentDescription,
            "remittanceInformation": {
                "type": "UNSTRUCTURED",
                "value": paymentReference
                },
            "paymentScheme": "SEPA_INSTANT_CREDIT_TRANSFER"
    };
    (async function(){
    response = await axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "https://api.ThirdParty.com/api/v1/pay",
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${clientAccessToken}`,},
        data: jsonData,
        })

        // We write a the payment request ID in the user's document
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const paymentRequestID = response.data.id;

        db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
            paymentRequestID: paymentRequestID
        }, { merge: true })
        .catch(function (error) {
            //handle error
            console.log(error);
            });
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
    })()
})
```

Am I on the right track thinking that this is an async problem?
Or is it a Firebase/Firestore issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not returning the promises returned by the asynchronous methods (`axios()` and `set()`), potentially generating some "erratic" behavior of the Cloud Function.

As you will see in the three videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the official [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) you MUST return a Promise or a value in a background triggered Cloud Function, to indicate to the platform that it has completed, and to avoid it is terminated before the asynchronous operations are done or it continues running after the work has been completed.

The following adaptations should do the trick (untested):

#### onCreate Function:

```
buildCredentials = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    // Request to Third party to generate an Client Access Token
    return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: "https://api.ThirdParty.com/api/v1/oauth/token",
        data: "client_id=xxx&client_secret=yyy&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=all:all",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" },
      })
        .then(function (response) {
          //handle success
          console.log('new user created: ')
          console.log(user.id);
          console.log(response.data);
        
          // We write a new document in the users collection with the user ID and the Client Access Token
          const db = admin.firestore();
          const newUser = {
            uid: user.uid,
            clientAccessToken: response.data.access_token
          };
    
          return db.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set(newUser)
    
        })
        .catch(function (response) {
          //handle error
          console.log(response);
          return null;
        });
    })
```

#### Callable Function:

```
exports.paymentRequest = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    
    try {
        
        const clientAccessToken = data.clientAccessToken;
        const recipientIban = data.recipientIban;
        const recipientName = data.recipientName;
        const paymentDescription = data.paymentDescription;
        const paymentReference = data.paymentReference;
        const productPrice = parseInt(data.productPrice);
        const uid = data.uid;
    
        const jsonData = {
            // ...
        };
        const response = await axios({
            method: "post",
            url: "https://api.ThirdParty.com/api/v1/pay",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${clientAccessToken}`,
            },
            data: jsonData,
        })
    
        // We write a the payment request ID in the user's document
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const paymentRequestID = response.data.id;
    
        await db.collection('users').doc(uid).set({
            paymentRequestID: paymentRequestID
        }, { merge: true })
            
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
        
    } catch (error) {
        
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors    
    
    }
    
})
```

Comment: Holy... That worked perfectly... Thank you so much, I wish there was a crypto tip option on stackoverflow because I spent so much time on this and your solution works flawlessly... I'll watch the videos you linked carefully. Thank you!